# Servidor tomcat 9.0 solo devuelve el primer servicio

Tags: java, rest, jpa, tomcat, jersey

Hola buenas tardes, formulo esta pregunta porque he buscado bastante por internet pero no he encontrado una solución a este problema.

El tema es que arranco el servidor y todo va como la seda, tengo varios servicios implementados, servicios PUT y GET, y al llamarlos a través de postman todos me devuelven una respuesta 200, siempre y cuando sea la primera solicitud después de arrancar el servidor. Es decir el segundo servicio y posteriores se pierden en el limbo, ya que la conexión es aceptada por el servidor.

Por supuesto he puesto puntos de ruptura en los servicios y he arrancado el servidor en "debug-mode" para ver si podía sacar algo de info pero todo ha sido en vano.

Adjunto imágenes de la consola del servidor, de la configuración del persistence.xml, ya que utilizo JPA con Hibernate como gestor de persistencia y del pom.xml. En principio creo que las anotaciones de JPA están bien, ya que el ide no me canta ningún error y en el primer servicio añado, borro y consulto registros de la base de datos. Añadir que utilizo Jersey como serializador.

Muchas gracias de antemano, espero que me puedan ayudar. :)

EDITO:
He conseguido aislar los los fallos, y estos son en los servicios GET, los servicios PUT funcionan bien. Parece ser que hay algún problema con la conexión a la base de datos, ya que cuando se queda "colgado" si intento acceder a los registros de la base de datos a través de la consola mysql, la consulta no es devuelta hasta que cierro el servidor a lo bruto (pulsando el botón "terminate") añado el stacktrace del error más abajo. Muchas gracias again.

**Información de la consola del servidor, del persistance.xml y del pom.xml:**
[image: Primera conexión aceptada y devuelta]

[image: Segunda conexión aceptada pero sin respuesta]

[image: Configuración del persistance.xml]

[image: Configuración pom.xml parte 1]

[image: Configuración pom.xml parte 2]

> INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@5eb3a986] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
>   INFORMACIÓN: Se ha recibido un comando de apagado a través del puerto de apagado. Parando la instancia del Servidor.
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFORMACIÓN: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
>   INFORMACIÓN: Parando servicio [Catalina]
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
>   INFORMACIÓN: Esperando por [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtWRc.png) instancia(s) para recuperar su espacio reservado
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
>   INFORMACIÓN: Esperando por [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtWRc.png) instancia(s) para recuperar su espacio reservado
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
>   INFORMACIÓN: Esperando por [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtWRc.png) instancia(s) para recuperar su espacio reservado
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
>   ADVERTENCIA: La aplicación web [ILoan] registró el conductor JDBC [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] pero falló al anular el registro mientras la aplicación web estaba parada. Para prevenir un fallo de memoria, se ha anulado el registro del conductor JDBC por la fuerza.
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>   ADVERTENCIA: The web application [ILoan] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:[
>    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
>    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3005)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3466)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3897)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:525)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:429)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:245)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
>    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
>    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
>    org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
>    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
>    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>    daos.Dao.(Dao.java:14)
>    daos.FriendDao.(FriendDao.java:12)
>    deal.FriendDeal.(FriendDeal.java:13)
>    recursos.ResourceFriend.(ResourceFriend.java:23)
>    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
>    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
>    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
>    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
>    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
>    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
>    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:737)
>    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:707)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:300)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
>    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:409)
>    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)]
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>   ADVERTENCIA: The web application [ILoan] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>    java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
>    com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>   ADVERTENCIA: The web application [ILoan] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>   ADVERTENCIA: The web application [ILoan] appears to have started a thread named [pool-3-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>   ADVERTENCIA: The web application [ILoan] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   GRAVE: La aplicación web [ILoan] creó un ThreadLocal con clave del tipo [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (valor [java.lang.ThreadLocal@39c0db85]) y un valor del tipo [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] (valor [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors@42630ea9]) pero no pudo quitarlo cuando la aplicación web se paró. Los hilos se van a renovar con el tiempo para intentar evitar in posible fallo de memoria.
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   GRAVE: La aplicación web [ILoan] creó un ThreadLocal con clave del tipo [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (valor [java.lang.ThreadLocal@23fdc732]) y un valor del tipo [org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.Instance] (valor [Instance{id=37621d2c-f027-4731-b0e6-c0ec9732fb4a, referenceCounter=2, store size=3}]) pero no pudo quitarlo cuando la aplicación web se paró. Los hilos se van a renovar con el tiempo para intentar evitar in posible fallo de memoria.
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
>   INFORMACIÓN: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:07 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint shutdownExecutor
>   ADVERTENCIA: The executor associated with thread pool [http-nio-8080] has not fully shutdown. Some application threads may still be running.
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
>   INFORMACIÓN: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>   INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   may 16, 2018 10:06:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>   INFORMACIÓN: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que: "...se pierden en el limbo..."? ¿Cuándo arrancas en modo de depuración y pones los puntos de ruptura, entra a los servicios? ¿En caso contrario, qué ocurre?

Comment: Hola @E.Betanzos, si te fijas en la última línea de la consola del servidor dice "INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess" es decir, ha recibido la petición. Después no ocurre nada, tanto postman como soapUI se quedan esperando una respuesta que nunca llega. En cuanto a los puntos de ruptura, si es la primera vez que accedo al servicio desde el arranque del servidor, si entra, si es la segunda o posteriores no entran. Me da la sensación de que en la primera consulta no cierra la conexión pero he puesto bloques try catch en cada paso de la conexión con idéntica response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema son los bucles infinitos que se crean en las consultas a la base de datos. Cuando un **Usuario** tiene muchos **Amigos** y un **Amigo** puede pertenecer a muchos **Usuarios**(One to many y Many to one, relacion bidireccional), si no se mapea bien, se pueden generar bucles infinitos que saturen la base de datos. 
Añado este tutorial en el que se explican muy bien las relaciones bidireccionales. Este es el mejor artículo que he podido encontrar.
[Artículo sobre relaciones bidireccionales](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

**EDITO:**

Añado un nuevo tutorial.
[Tutorial sobre relaciones JPA](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm)